# TLS Error: socket hang up in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sockets, ubuntu, ssl

I'am trying to connect on a server using tls in nodejs. Here is my code :

```
var options = {
  rejectUnauthorized: false //self signed certificate
};
co = require("tls").connect(5200, "my_host", options, function(){
   co.on("data", function(data) {
      //do domething
   })

}
```

This is simplified code. If I catch the error event, I have a `ECONNRESET` error, if I don't, I've got this trace :

```
Error: socket hang up
at SecurePair.error (tls.js:1001:23)
at EncryptedStream.CryptoStream._done (tls.js:697:22)
at EncryptedStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:493:12)
at EncryptedStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:320:10)
at CleartextStream.onCryptoStreamFinish (tls.js:301:47)
at CleartextStream.g (events.js:175:14)
at CleartextStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
at finishMaybe (_stream_writable.js:354:12)
at endWritable (_stream_writable.js:361:3)
at CleartextStream.Writable.end (_stream_writable.js:339:5)
```

If I connect directly to my server using `openssl s_client -connect my_host:5200` it works great. Strange thing, with node version 0.10.*, it works on ubuntu 10.04, but not on my mac neither on ubuntu 12.04. My server is also a nodejs program running ubuntu 10.04. Not sure if all of this is related but any help would be great !
Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what your client/server are doing, there may be a timing issue here.  You want to set your event-handlers outside the callback to ensure they are setup before data is flowing.  Try this:

```
var options = {
  rejectUnauthorized: false //self signed certificate
};
co = require("tls").connect(5200, "my_host", options, function(){
  //do something
});

co.on("data", function(data) {
  //do something
});
```